# How to run the same unittest class for a list of class instances

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, object, instance

I have a variable list of class instances:

```
instances = get_all_instances()
print(instances)
>> [<yy object at 0x00000191A43B8668>, <xx object at 0x00000191B3C0FF98>,.....]
```

I also have a test class:

```
class test_instances(unittest.TestCase)
    def setup(self)
        self.instance = instance
    def test_01(self):
        # Uses self.instance.....
        .....
```

How can I get unittest to test each instance using that unittest class with the current setup by setting self.instance to the instance to be tested each time?

Edit: I do not want to instantiate the classes for each test function and looping through them in each test as instances must be the same throughout.

Comment: Any reason for not doing `self.instances = get_all_instances()` and then iterating over it in each test method? Unless `get_all_instances` is particularly slow I think that would be easier to achieve

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah this was the only solution I could think of but would mean editing quite a large amount of code as well as tests running in parallel rather than one after each other. Was hoping there was a simple solution which I just haven't been able to find in the documentation!